# Which set is this school themed sticker a part of?

Tags: set-identification

[image: lego part]

Who can help find the set this belongs to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's from set [266 "Child's Bedroom"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=266-1), released in 1974:

[image: Set 266]

Comment: And in those days it was still a common practice to place stickers across bricks, which in AFOL parlay is called a STAMP (STicker Across Multiple Parts).

Comment: I know Bricklink uses the term "stickered assembly" instead. But, alas, the assemblies for these old sets are not in the database.

Comment: @PhilB. and then you end up with broken stickers :( I have most of a Fabuland fire station set with a couple of those assemblies